# How to display Germany Umlauts (ü, ä, ö) from sql in Php?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am trying to display this German character the proper way, if I don't use `htmlentities()` the output is **unabh�ngig**, but when I try to use `htmlentities()` the word is missing, why is that?

```
<?php
$str = htmlentities("unabhängig");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<div><?php echo $str;?></div>
```

Comment: Make sure your encoding is not being forced by apache or htaccess.  I've seen similar situation even choose utf-8 in meta, the encoding appears different.  for that you need change htaccess. you can check by clicking encoding on your browser and see what is selected when you view your site. also the meta format : <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: you didn't say it comes from database. make your database connection is utf-8 and you can pass utf-8 to htmlentities

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with the ü, ä, etc.

Right after selecting the database I implemented this two lines:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

as suggested here:
http://www.flashhilfe.de/forum/serverseitige-programmierung/php-mysql-wie-utf-8-beim-connect-festlegen-225225-225225.html

Best, Yannis

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to send ü without encoding it separately by ensuring that the charset is set to utf-8 using HTTP header.

If for some reason you can't do that, use:

```
Ü = &Uuml;
```

or

```
ü = &uuml;
```

Comment: Probably I can hardcode it that way, but the words come from a database.

Answer (score 0):

This is the format for charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Make sure your encoding is not being forced by htaccess or apache. check what is the selected encoding in your browser when you view the site, if it is not utf-8, then it is being forced. If forced you can add this to htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Make sure your database table is in utf-8

Make sure your connection to your database is in utf-8 http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);
```

You can pass UTF-8 encoding to htmlentities to make it use correct encoding. or you can use htmlspecialchars  http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: The charset was already correct HTML5, what you suggested is the HTML4 standard. Since he's using the HTML5 doctype, there is no need to change. [From the W3C](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#quicklookup)

Comment: I see, thanks for the info I didn't know this. though more browser version support shouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't want to worry about so many different charset codings or if htmlentities doesn't work for you, here the alternative:
I used mysqli DB connection (and PHPV5)  Form post for writing/inserting to MySQl DB.

```
$Notes = $_POST['Notes']; //can be text input or textarea.

$Notes = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $Notes);  //double quotes for mailto: emails.  
$von = array("ä","ö","ü","ß","Ä","Ö","Ü"," ","é");  //to correct double whitepaces as well
$zu  = array("&auml;","&ouml;","&uuml;","&szlig;","&Auml;","&Ouml;","&Uuml;","&nbsp;","&#233;");  
$Notes = str_replace($von, $zu, $Notes);  
echo " Notes:".$Notes."<br>" ;  
$Notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Notes); //for recommended mysqli DB connection.
//$Notes = mysql_real_escape_string($Notes); //for old deprecated mysql DB connection.

// mysqli_real_escape_string Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

echo " Notes:".$Notes ;  //ready for inserting
enter code here
//Optional:     
$charset = mysqli_character_set_name($link);  //only works for mysqli DB connection
printf ("To check your character set but not necessary %s\n",$charset);
```

Comment: And add this line in the header if funny characters appear.<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">